# OpenGL rotating towards a point

Tags: c++, math, opengl

Using openGL (just 2d), I'm trying to rotate a texture so it's pointing towards a point on screen. I'll show an image first to help me explain.

http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3088/probe.png

Say my texture is the blue dot at point 1 and it is moving to its destination at point 2. I want to rotate #1 so that it is "pointing" towards point 2 (the texture is a bird so it has a defined "front"). To do this, I need to find out angle 3. Similarly, if my bird is at point #4 travelling towards point 5, I need to work out angle 6.

What's the secret to doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is the super-useful `std::atan2` function. Subtract the current position from the target position of a bird, and stuff `y` and `x` (note the order!) into `atan2` to get the angle.

**Edit:** Note that atan usually assumes 0° to be at the X+ axis (right). However, you seem to align your 'base direction' to Y+ instead (up), so you might want to subtract 90° or fiddle with the order and signs of parameters to the atan functions (using the basic symmetries in a circle, i.e. `atan2(-x,y)`).

Comment: Sounds good, but quit hard to understand, I do not get what you exactly mean.

Comment: This is great, I knew I needed something along these lines but unfortunately my math is quite weak so I needed a bit more guidance. Thanks!

Comment: @ltjax: I don't want to be taxed as pedant, but I'm curious why you use _substract_ rather than _subtract_. Just FWIW, [Subtract vs Substract](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/subtract-vs-substract). That's just my curiosity, please don't take it as pedantry.

Comment: @jweyrich: Thanks for the hint, I fixed it! I can never remember which one is right, especially since I usually just write "-" :)

Comment: This completely annihilates the process of typical "cylinder billboarding" and is actually way simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Say your target position is at T, and your sprites position is P, then the vector T-P points into the direction from P to T. So you've to align your texture in that direction. You don't need to do trigonometry for this! So here is how it goes:

T.x and T.y are the x and y positions of T, and in the same way P.x and P.y for P. The vector T - P => (T.x - P.x, T.y - P.z) = D_l. We want this vector to be normalized, which can be done by scaling the elements of the vector with 1/length(D_l). So we obtain D_l by

```
D.x = D_l.x / sqrt( D.x^2 + D.y^2 ) = (T.x - P.x) / sqrt( (T.x - P.x)^2 + (T.y - P.y)^2 )
D.y = D_l.y / sqrt( D.x^2 + D.y^2 ) = (T.y - P.y) / sqrt( (T.x - P.x)^2 + (T.y - P.y)^2 )
```

and just for completenes

```
D.z = 0
```

So D is now the vector containing the direction toward the target, i.e. the Up-direction for the sprite. Now we need the Right-direction. We could now do some fancy tricks with slopes, but there's a leaner way: We want to find the vector perpendicular to the plane spanned by the direction vector and the vector looking down onto the scene, i.e. the Z direction. I.e. we want to find the cross product yielding the bi-direction D × Z = B

Remembering the definition of the cross product, and considering Z.x = Z.y = 0, Z.z = 1

```
B.x = D.y · Z.z - D.z · Z.y =  D.y
B.y = D.z · Z.x - D.x · Z.z = -D.x
B.z = D.x · Z.y - D.y · Z.x = 0
```

Just like expected B.z = 0. From this you can create the rotation matrix:

```
B.x   D.x   0   0 
B.y   D.y   0   0 
 0     0    1   0 
 0     0    0   1 

 =

 D.y   D.x   0   0
-D.x   D.y   0   0 
  0     0    1   0 
  0     0    0   1
```

which is a orthonormal matrix and thus describes a rotation. You can apply the rotation this matrix using `glMultMatrix`, or if you want to put the position therein, too, then load the following vaiant using `glLoadMatrix`

```
B.x   D.x   0   P.x
B.y   D.y   0   P.y
 0     0    1   P.z
 0     0    0    1
```